# How to use String.skip function in proper way?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a text file contains around 8000 lines. 
Each lines must have 90 characters.
Each lines contain different blocks so I have to use substring for each blocks.
For Eg.
xx-xxxxxxxxx-xx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

I use Substring(x,x) to get each block in for loop.

Some of lines have do not have 122 characters,

For Eg. xx-xxxxxxxxx-xx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxx

so i would like to skip those lines and proceed for others. I don't understand the proper use of String.Skip function in C#.

Here is my code.

```
public void getext()
{

    // bool check = false;
    MySqlConnectionStringBuilder con = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    con.Server = "xxx";
    con.UserID = "xxx";
    con.Password = "xxx";
    con.Database = "xxx";
    MySqlConnection sqlcon = new MySqlConnection(con.ToString());
    string padding = "";

    try
    {
        sqlcon.Open();
        //var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var path = "C:\\xxx\\xxx\\xxx\\1.txt";
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
        for (var i = 0; i < lines.Length; i += 1)
        {
            string str = lines[i].ToString();
            string code, control1, actype, control2, filler, control3, sponsor,
            control4, amtdate, control5;                
            code = str.Substring(0, 2);
            control1 = str.Substring(2, 9);
            actype = str.Substring(11, 2);
            control2 = str.Substring(13, 18);
            filler = str.Substring(31, 40);
            control3 = str.Substring(74, 16);
            sponsor = str.Substring(90, 20);                
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("addext", sqlcon);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("code", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = code;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("control1", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = control1;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("actype", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = actype;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("control2", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = control2;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("filler", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = filler;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("control3", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = control3;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("sponsor", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sponsor;                
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //sqlcon.Close();
            label1.Visible = true;
            //sqlcon.Close();
            //watch.Stop();
            //var elapsedMs = watch.Elapsed.TotalMinutes;
            label1.Text = "success";
            // sqlcon.Close();

        }
        sqlcon.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        label1.Visible = true;
        label1.Text = "fail" + ex.ToString();
    }

}
```

Comment: `if(str.Length != 122){ continue; }`, maybe?

Comment: `String` implements `IEnumerable<char>` and `Skip` is an extension method on `IEnumerable`. It skip a number of characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to skip lines which are less than 122 characters? You can filter them out from your loop and process only the ones that have required length.

```
foreach(var str in lines.Where(x=>x.Length>=122))
{
string code, control1, actype, control2, filler, control3, sponsor,
            control4, amtdate, control5;                
code = str.Substring(0, 2);

// rest of your code
}
```

The Filter and Foreach approach would keep away the indices, increasing readability of the code

Comment: If you're going to do this, please use a proper `foreach` loop (*not* `ForEach()`) and skip the call to `ToList()` ... Especially if your file can be anything sizable. This is poor form in general. `foreach(var line in lines.Where(x => x.Length>=122)){...}` should suffice (or see the other answer for use of the `continue` keyword)

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Thanks, you are right. I have updated the answer reflecting the same

Answer (score 2):

If you want to skip a number/line within your loop you can use

```
continue;
```

example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < lines.Length; i += 1)
{
    string str = lines[i];

    if (str.length != 122) // We only want to Work with lines which are 122 chars long.
        continue;

    DoWork(); // Insert you code here ;)
}
```

Comment: Note that `.ToString()` is quite useless here as `lines` is a `string` array, so `lines[i]` already is a `string`

Comment: @Rafalon Copy&Paste from his code ;-) Did remove the `.ToString()`

Comment: Yup I knew that. But I think `>=` should be `<=` here, or `!= 122`, or `< 122` as he said he wanted to skip the lines which *do not have 122 characters*

Comment: Thanks for replying. It did not work. I placed continue and after the rest of the code. However, it goes to check condition but it does not perform steps after continue.

Comment: @RexJones be careful **not to** write a `{` after `if(str.Length != 122)`, **or else** add a `}` after `continue;`

Comment: @Rafalon I followed your example.